# Building raster indicating whether slope is positive or negative moving from start location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, slope

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 (advanced user license), and I am wondering if there is any method to have ArcGIS calculate (for each cell of a slope raster in degrees) whether the slope is negative or positive, considering a movement from starting location outwards.

I found some threads (https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/03/09/calculating-the-slope-of-a-hiking-trail/; [Calculating slope for points with downhill slopes rendered as negatives in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154260/calculating-slope-for-points-with-downhill-slopes-rendered-as-negatives-in-arcgi)) in which they were discussing a similar BUT NOT identical issue, and the solution was actually implying some coding I am not familiar with.

Is there any means to accomplish what I am after?

Comment: Can you expand on, may be with an image, what you mean by "starting location outwards", from a single cell there are 8 possible ways outwards?

Comment: Hello. I was referring to the possibility to have a raster indicating whether the slope is negative or positive. Of course, that implies to know the direction of moment, since if going from A to B entails crossing a cell with a positive slope, going from B to A would entail walking along a negative slope. So, assuming we have a given location, is it possible to have a raster in which all the surrounding cells (i.e., all the cells thought which I can move in all the 8 directions) have a signed (i.e., NOT absolute) slope value?

Comment: A raster cell can only hold 1 value. For example lets say going directly north is positive,east is positive, south is positive and west is negative. That's four values. I'm not sure I have understood what you are asking? You want to "store" all those combinations in a single cell? That's not possible.